# How can I send an e-mail with these fields? For example, {{x.vessel}} will be the e-mail subject

Tags: php, html, angularjs

I'm using PHP, angular.js and HTML. I just want to send an e-mail with the fields below (like {{x.vessel}} that will be the subject)

```
<tr ng-repeat="x in names">
    <td>{{x.vessel}}</td>
    <td>{{x.imo}}</td>
    <td>{{x.callsign}}</td>
    <td>{{x.voyageno}}</td>
    <td>{{x.latitude}}</td>
    <td>{{x.longitude}}</td>
    <td>{{x.port}}</td>
    <td>{{x.created_at}}</td>
    </tr>
 </table>
<br />
```

How can I send an e-mail with this body? (note that {{x.vessel}} is the e-mail subject)

```
 <div class="form-group">
 <a href="mailto:xxx@xxxxx.com?body={{x.vessel}}">Send mail</a>
 </div>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Can you give me an example on how I can do this?

Comment: You need to declare your variable `{{x.vessel}}` or set it probably via jquery or js.

Comment: There is a good example in Code Project that shows how to setup an email application with Angular, HTML and PHP: https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/1246923/How-do-I-send-an-email-from-website-with-angularjs

Comment: I got a **form** already; im inserting my data infos, select from my database with that. Im trying to send email with my selected datas... {{x.vessel}} is one of them. It is angularjs but i need to transform it to php then i can use i guess...